# How to select audio input device (mic) in AVAudioEngine on macOS / swift?

Tags: swift, macos, microphone, avaudioengine, sfspeechrecognizer

Is it possible to select the input device in `AVAudioEngine` using Swift on macOS?

*Use case:*

I am using `SFSpeechRecognizer` on macOS.

To feed microphone data into it I am using

```swift
private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
:

let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

inputNode.installTap( onBus: 0,  bufferSize: 1024,  format: recordingFormat )
{ (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer, when: AVAudioTime) in
    self.recognitionRequest?.append( buffer )
}

audioEngine.prepare()
try audioEngine.start()
```

This will use the system default microphone.

I have an external USB microphone I wish to use instead. I can go into System Preferences -> Audio and set the default output device to my USB microphone. Then it will work. But if I disconnect the microphone and reconnect it to a different USB port, I will have to go through the process of setting it as default again.

To avoid having to do this repeatedly, I would like to set the microphone manually from code.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I found [Set AVAudioEngine Input and Output Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781283/set-avaudioengine-input-and-output-devices) which uses Obj-C.

Comment: It's been a while, but were you able to figure this out? I'm coming across the same issue.